# Google dataflow api is returning empty result

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

The below api is returning an empty dictionary.

```
curl \
  'https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/jobs?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Please throw some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Using projects.jobs.list is not recommended, as you can only get the list of jobs that are running in us-central1. Do you have running jobs in us-central1?
See the [projects.jobs.list method documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/list)

You could try this instead:

```
curl \
  'https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/jobs?view=JOB_VIEW_ALL&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

[JobView Reference](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/JobView)